# While Tomcat is running at the same time tomcat acquiring the log file that time not able to delete the log file

Tags: tomcat

While Tomcat is running at the same time tomcat acquiring the log file that time not able to delete the log file.
 When we trying to delete the log file Windows showing below error message.
 " **It is being using by another person or program** "

I need to delete the log file when tomcat is running state.

Can any one help me to solve this issue...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot delete the log file while Tomcat is running.

Please mention in detail your requirement, what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Actual requirement is to delete the log file when the method process completed.

Comment: You can't have this type of behavior, as file is opened by tomcat in write mode. You can try rollingfileappender with some file size, on reaching the maximum file size given, file's lock will be released and a new file will be created.

Comment: File size is not a matter. Delete the log file when ever user decides and with out stop the tomcat. can u tell me is it possible or not.